# Lost Office 365 Developer Admin Account after enabling 2-factor authentication

Tags: office365

I have a problem with my Office 365 Developer admin account. This account is in the form username@*****.onmicrosoft.com and the account used to register with Office 365 is different from this one. After enabling 2-factor Authentication I can not login back. The Office 365 Developer Dashboard does not help!
Please provide an idea to resolve this problem!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to MS Office's technical support? Sounds like an [off topic] question for this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is for programming questions, and this clearly isn't one